# Error attempting to login to Magento admin, frontend still works OK

Tags: magento

Magento v1.8 CE, CentOS 6.

Magento has been working fine all day, I've been updating a few products, nothing major at all and certainly not installing new extensions or themes.  The last thing I remember doing was [in the admin UI] flushing the cache in response to a message from Magento saying I should.

Now I can't access my store's admin URL.  The frontend appears to be working fine, but whenever I access the http://www.domain.com/admin URL it throws an error to /var/report.  Error text pasted below.  I'm at a loss to understand what this could be - can anyone help please?

The "License file is invalid" at the first few characters of the log before line 0 has me confused too.  License file?  For what?  The only thing I have installed which isn't default Magento is M2EPro.

I've tried restarting mysqld, httpd and even out of desperation rebooted the VPS - same problem every time.

Desperate for any suggestions please.

Thanks,

```
a:5:{i:0;s:24:"License file is invalid.";i:1;s:3485:"#0 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/local/VES/Core/Model/Observer.php(6) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1): VES_Core_Helper_Data->getExtensionList()
#1 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): VES_Core_Model_Observer->core_block_abstract_to_html_after(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(VES_Core_Model_Observer), 'core_block_abst...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(910): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#7 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(605): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(549): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)
#9 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')
#10 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/s...')
#11 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#12 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#19 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#20 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /var/www/html/MYDOMAIN.COM/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}";s:3:"url";s:70:"/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/d9191ab4bf67d359aabb5bcc6cc7a72f/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}[root@electrichippo report
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extension called `VES_Core` on your instance.
Try disabling that and all the modules that depend on it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me today. I de-activated the app/etc/modules/VES_Core.xml and app/etc/modules/VES_AdvancedPdfProcessor.xml

Now I can access my admin again. Wonder what happened and why my amdin shuts down when their (EasyPDF) website is down :-(

Answer (score -1):

happened the same to me right now, no maintenance done, no edits. 
I think it's because of the EasyPDF extension: if you check their site ( http://www.vnecoms.com/ ) it is offline, maybe something linked there went wrong, I don't really know!